# Creating great circles map with R

Tags: r, for-loop, dictionary, great-circle

All,
  I am trying to create a map with "Great Circles" similar to what Nathan Yau did in this [posting](http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/).  However, I am trying to do it for the whole world and all coming into a single location.  I seem to be having problems with the loop section of it. If I just use one lat/long combo, everything works. As soon as I build out my table larger I get errors (`Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1)` : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2)  I am a 100% newb at R and would love some help

**lat.txt**

```
LAT,LONG  
39.164141,-121.640625
```

**R commands**

```
library(maps)  
library(geosphere)  
lat_me <- 45.213004  
lon_me <- -68.906250  
map("world", col="#f2f2f2", plot = TRUE, fill=TRUE, bg="white")  
data <- read.csv("/Users/blah/R/latlon/lat.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)  
for (i in 1:length(data)) {  
  inter <- gcIntermediate(c(data$LONG, data$LAT), c(lon_me, lat_me), n=50, addStartEnd=TRUE)  
  lines(inter,col="red")  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was actually just cut+paste from R. The + symbols are just graphically representing the "for" loop I believe

Comment: I suggest you don't use a loop, since `gcIntermediate` is already vectorised.

Comment: @Andrie Can you elaborate a little? I am doing my research right now on why I what I could do instead, but for this I was following the example given by Nathan. –

Comment: Some time ago I posted some code using `lattice` graphics [here](http://procomun.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/great-circles/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you index your loop with `i` but dont include that anywhere inside the loop.
I imagine that you want to loop over the rows of your data. So change the index range to 1:nrow(data), and include the index for the row you want do draw for each i.

```
for( i in 1:nrow(data)){
inter <- gcIntermediate(c(data$LONG[i], data$LAT[i]), 
                        c(lon_me, lat_me), 
                        n=50, 
                        addStartEnd=TRUE)
...
}
```

Comment: Wow... that certainly worked.  That solved my exact question perfectly

Comment: @bread555, welcome to S.O. If this answer solved your question, please make sure to indicate by clicking on the green check-mark next to the question.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I certainly will, I was just waiting to see if anything else came in. However, I'll select it now.

Answer (score 4):

`gcIntermediate` is vectorsied (as pointed out by @Andrie in the comments), so you do not need a loop:

```
me <- c( 45.213004 , -68.906250   )

set.seed(123)
pts <- data.frame( x = runif(4,-180,180) , y = runif(4,-90,90) )
pts
#          x          y
#1 -76.47209  79.284111
#2 103.78985 -81.799830
#3 -32.76831   5.058988
#4 137.88627  70.635428

#  Just supply the two column data.frame - no need for loops!
#  Also return as 'SpatialLines' object to make plotting easier
inter <- gcIntermediate( pts , me , n=50 , addStartEnd=TRUE , sp = TRUE) 

map("world", col="#f2f2f2", plot = TRUE, fill=TRUE, bg="white") 
plot(inter ,add=T , col = "red" , lty = 2 )
```

[image]

Comment: @Simon0101 wow. Thanks for the further explanation. Looks like I am going to be looking alot of those terms/commands up because I haven't seen them before.  Specifically what do you mean by using SpatialLines for easier plotting?